# Format long not working when adding to structure

Tags: matlab, structure, long-integer

I am trying to add a number in Unix time to a structure (e.g.      1.500648654999999e+09), but even when I put format long it is being saved in an abbreviated way (1.5006e+09).

```
 format long
    TimeToAdd = BL05_tsq_StartTimes(1) - (4*3600);
    format long
    LFPinfo(i).startTime = LFPinfo(i).startTime+TimeToAdd;
```

Comment: `format` has nothing to due with the way the numbers are being stored.  It's sole effect is in how numbers get ***displayed*** when printed to the Command Window.  Your numbers are being stored to `double` precision irrespective of how they are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The summary of [`format`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) states

> Set Command Window output display format

It changes the output display format in the Command Window to the format specified by style. The computation and value stored in the memory wouldn't be affected by the `format` command.

To display the formatted string in the command window, you need to use [`fprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html), and specify the precision you prefer. For example:

```
fprintf('%.10f\n',LFPinfo(i).startTime)
```